# @SchemaValidation issue with weblogic's TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, xsd, weblogic11g

I have been troubled to the core with an issue with @SchemaValidation in combination with weblogic's TransformerFactoryImpl. I have written a few JAX-WS web services and I need to validate the messages by adding @SchemaValidation. But the problem is in my application I have done some transformation specific stuff where I have to use weblogic.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl factory otherwise my transformation fails. As soon as I add the system property to specify my transformer factory my deployment starts failing because of @SchemaValidation annotation.It starts giving errors like:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'xmlns:tns' cannot appear in element 'schema'

Everything works fine if I remove the @SchemaValidation annotation. Can anyone please help me, it has become a major issue and i couldnt find much help on net.

Thanks a lot,
A

Comment: Hello, any help on this one please???

Answer (score 0):

As per the following error you gave the issue may not be related to TransformerFactoryImpl but rather in your WSDL. Can you try removing the namespace declaration for xmlns:tns from the schema element? so that it uses name space declared at global level i.e. declared in the definitions tag.